# Is it impolite to say hello to a doctor as "Hi, First Name"?

Tags: politeness, canadian-english

I'm based in Canada and I'm not a native English speaker. Is it impolite to call doctors and dentists by their first name instead of "Dr. Last Name" when answering a phone call?

Comment: Unless you happen to know them non-professionally, it is impolite.

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about social customs, not about the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thirty years ago, ‘Hi, First Name’ addressed to a medical doctor (or, for that matter, anybody else that one does not know well) would have been shockingly improper. Nowadays, such forms of address have become fairly common in North America, even among relative strangers, and quite a few medical doctors are not at all offended by being so addressed. It is, however, still disrespectful to *presume* that such a form of address is O.K., *until* one is given some indication that it is. A polite person will therefore say something like ‘Good morning, Doctor Last Name’ when making an *initial* contact, and will then be sensitive to any indications that the doctor gives as to what level of formality is expected.

Comment: I used to call my patients "Mr. X", "Ms. Y", etc. Unless they were my friends or became my friends, it was more respectful to them and kept the dynamic more balanced. I hate when people who don't know me call me "honey", "sweetie", or some other familiar slang, although I suspect if someone started with, "Hey, gorgeous", I don't think I'd be offended.